# What to do about [CSS] questions tagged [styling]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

The [styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/styling) tag has the following description:

> styling is the process of binding visual metadata to a document

Of 1 155 questions, about half are also tagged [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css). An unknown amount of questions are also tagged [styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/styling) but not [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), but are in fact about CSS. Those questions are less likely to receive attention by an expert in the field, since they are badly tagged.

I think something should be done here, but I am not sure what. Perhaps the description of [styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/styling) should be updated with something like this:

> For questions about CSS, use [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css).

Perhaps the old questions should be retagged, and it could even be debated wheater the styling tag deserves to exist at all. The tags [styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/styles) and [stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheets) have already had "DO NOT USE!" added to them.

What do you think should be done here? Perhaps I am just being pedantic?

Comment: It should be marked *DO NOT USE*. And people should be asked to use *specific tags* instead. About 70 percent of *styling* questions are related to CSS

Comment: Have you done any research about the quality of those questions? It might be a prejudice, but if you're asking a question about styling (in CSS) and you don't use the CSS-tag, why should I invest time in it anyway? What would be the impact of my answer?

Comment: I haven't made any systematic review, but the reason I came across this was because of questions in the close vote queue... But even if the questions are terrible, don't we want them to show up in the right tags so people can educate posters, downvote and close?

Comment: @pnuts - Well, we need to start somewhere :).  The problem is there are lots of  tags on SO which are almost always used with some other *specific* tag. If asking people politely not use these tags don't work, then we will have to have stricter measures like closing down such questions

Comment: It would be so nice with a feature that blocked posts containing tags marked "DO NOT USE".

Comment: What I meant was not to automatically close the questions, but more something along the lines of a pedagogic message asking you to change the tags when you hit submit or even better just hiding the tags so users can not even enter them. But I agree that it is a topic for another thread.